# "Array index out of range: 1" when trying to repaint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to draw free form lines in java but I'm getting an Array index out of range: 1 error and I can't figure out why. It seems like It's happening during the call of the repaint() method. Am I doing something wrong with my vector? The way that I add my Point objects?(It seems like I'm maybe not adding anything to my vector?).

```
private int iterationDeLigne = 0;

private Vector<Point> locationDepart = new Vector<Point>();
private Vector<Point> locationArrivee = new Vector<Point>();

private class EcouteurDessin implements MouseListener
{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        MouseIsPressed = true;
        locationDepart.add(e.getPoint());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}

private class EcouteurMouvement implements MouseMotionListener
{

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        locationArrivee.add(e.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {} 
}

private class Panel_Graphique extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //switch()
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if(MouseIsPressed == true)
        {
            g.drawLine((int)locationDepart.get(iterationDeLigne).getX(), (int)locationDepart.get(iterationDeLigne).getY(),
                    (int)locationArrivee.get(iterationDeLigne).getX(), (int)locationArrivee.get(iterationDeLigne).getY());
            iterationDeLigne++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never compare a boolean to true or false. Just say `if( MouseIsPressed)` or `if( !MouseIsPressed)` That assumes that MouseIsPressed is a boolean variable (you do not show its definition).Regardless, as a variable name it should begin with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like It's happening during the call of the repaint() method

```
iterationDeLigne++;
```

A painting method is for painting only. You should not be changing the property of your class in the painting method, because you can't control when or how often Swing will repaint the component.

I don't really know what you are attempting to do but in general the paintComponent() method should:

1. invoke super.paintComponent(...) as the first statement to clear the background
2. Iterate through your ArrayList to repaint all the Points in the List.

Also, before asking a question like this do some basic debugging and tell us the exact statement causing the problem. The Exception trace will tell you the line number of the statement causing the problem.

Do help you debug, instead of using code like:

```
g.drawLine((int)locationDepart.get(iterationDeLigne).getX(), (int)locationDepart.get(iterationDeLigne).getY(), (int)locationArrivee.get(iterationDeLigne).getX(), (int)locationArrivee.get(iterationDeLigne).getY());
```

Not only does the above code not fit on a single line, you can't tell where the problem is in the statement.

So simplify the code to something like:

```
Point depart = locationDepart.get( iterationDeLigne );
Point arrivee = locationArrivee.get( iterationDeLigne );
g.drawLine(depart.x, depart.y, arrive.x, arrive,y);
```

Now you will know if the problem is when you access either of the ArrayLists or the drawLine(..) method. It is easier to debug as you can display the value of each variable as well.

Comment: @FredK, Please delete your comment as it has nothing to do with my answer. If you want to advise the OP how Java indexes work then add that as a comment to the question.  As I suggested in my answer the problem is that the "iterationDeLigne" variable is incremented in the paintComponent() method which will ultimately cause this exception since you can't control how often the method is invoked.